# Cannot access to ViewModel variables inside of Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I need to access to ViewModel variables inside of Fragment, here's my code :

```
class FacetFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facet, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())[ViewModel::class.java]

    val facetList: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.facetList)

    facetList.let {
        it.adapter = viewModel.adapterFacet
        it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        it.autoScrollToStart(viewModel.adapterFacet)
    }
    (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).let {
        it.setSupportActionBar(view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        it.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

}

And I have a bug for this line : `it.adapter = viewModel.adapterFacet` but the variable adapterFacet exists in the ViewModel... 
How to get this variable ?

I would be very grateful for your help :)

Comment: "And I have a bug for this line" - It would be helpful if you explain what the "bug" is :)

Answer (score 0):

Make `viewModel.adapterFacet` internal or public, you will be able to access it.

Notes:

1- you create memory leak by keep adapter inside view model, expose list needed to populate your adapter to your fragment and keep adapter instance inside your fragment not in view model

2- You can use apply instead of let and remove `it.` or use with method

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the error is still here... Unresolved reference: adapterFacet

Comment: The project is mainly written in Java, and I just need Kotlin for a few fragments. But, I noticed that the import 'kotlinx.android.synthetic' does not work, do you think that this is the problem ?

Comment: you can edit your original post and add your view model to be able to help you, and if you face any compilation error you should mention it.